# Pandas - Convert columns to new rows after groupby

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pivot

I have a pandas dataframe. I need to convert some of the columns into rows. The dataframe has same data in the first two columns for every 3 rows. So, I need 6 more columns as you will see in my expected dataframe.
I have the following dataframe:

```
shopCode    Product   Code  Score
    111      Apple    123    0.70
    111      Apple    456    0.75
    111      Apple    789    0.80
    222      Orange   142    0.66
    222      Orange   136    0.83
    222      Orange   623    0.76
```

My expected dataframe is:

```
shopCode  Product   Code1 Code2 Code3 Score1 Score2 Score3
  111      Apple     123   456   789   0.70   0.75   0.80
  222      Orange    142   136   623   0.66   0.83   0.76
```

I tried to use 
`df.pivot(index=['shopCode', 'Product'], columns=['Code1', 'Code2', 'Code3', 'Score1', 'Score2', 'Score3'], values=['Code', 'Score'])` 
but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We using `pivot_table`

```
df=pd.pivot_table(df,index=['shopCode','Product'],columns=df.groupby(['shopCode','Product']).cumcount().add(1),values=['Code','Score'],aggfunc='sum')
df.columns=df.columns.map('{0[0]}{0[1]}'.format) 
df
Out[112]: 
                  Code1  Code2  Code3  Score1  Score2  Score3
shopCode Product                                             
111      Apple      123    456    789    0.70    0.75    0.80
222      Orange     142    136    623    0.66    0.83    0.76
```

After `reset_index`

```
df.reset_index()
Out[113]: 
   shopCode Product  Code1  Code2  Code3  Score1  Score2  Score3
0       111   Apple    123    456    789    0.70    0.75    0.80
1       222  Orange    142    136    623    0.66    0.83    0.76
```

Answer (score 2):

Can be achieved with pandas groupby and dictionary merge.

```
df.groupby(['shopCode', 'Product']).apply(lambda x: pd.Series(
                               {
                                **{'Code'+str(i+1): t for i,t in enumerate(x.Code)},
                                **{'Score'+str(i+1): t for i,t in enumerate(x.Score)}
                               }
                             )).reset_index()
```

Comment: With that code you won't get rows as column!

Comment: it needs unstack() function to convert rows into columns. ...unstack().reset_index()