# Pandas - converting columns into rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame like this:

```
+-------+-----------+
| File  |  Column   |
+-------+-----------+
| File1 | FirstName |
| File1 | LastName  |
| File2 | ID        |
| File2 | City      |
| File2 | State     |
+-------+-----------+
```

How could I group the `File` column and pass the respective `Column` values as rows? i.e.:

```
+-------+-----------+----------+-------+
| File  |   Col1    |   Col2   | Col3  |
+-------+-----------+----------+-------+
| File1 | FirstName | LastName | NaN   |
| File2 | ID        | City     | State |
+-------+-----------+----------+-------+
```

I'm thinking I need to pivot it and pass `File` as the index and `Column` as the values:

```py
df.pivot(index='File', columns='', values='Column')
```

But here's where I'm stumped - I'm unsure what to pass for the `columns` parameter, or even if pivot is what I need.

Comment: Have you had a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47849364/pandas-convert-columns-to-new-rows-after-groupby)

Comment: @razdi Thank you, that was very helpful! I did not find that earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
df = pd.pivot_table(df,index=['File'], columns=df.groupby(['File']).cumcount().add(1), values=['Column'],aggfunc='sum')
df.columns=df.columns.map('{0[0]}{0[1]}'.format)
```

Found the answer using:

[Pandas - Convert columns to new rows after groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47849364/pandas-convert-columns-to-new-rows-after-groupby)

Answer (score 1):

One way to do thanks to @razdi comment and @WeNYoBen comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47849462/10041823).

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([["File1", "FirstName"],
                   ["File1", "LastName"],
                   ["File2", "ID"],
                   ["File2", "City"],
                   ["File2", "State"], ],
                  columns=["File", "Column"])

df = pd.pivot_table(df, index=['File'], columns=df.groupby(['File']).cumcount().add(1), values=['Column'], aggfunc='sum')
print(df)
#           Column
#                1         2      3
# File
# File1  FirstName  LastName    NaN
# File2         ID      City  State

df = df.reset_index()
print("df2: ", df)
#       File     Column
#                   1         2      3
# 0  File1  FirstName  LastName    NaN
# 1  File2         ID      City  State

df.columns = ["Col" + str(i) for i in range(len(df.columns))]
print(df)
#     Col0       Col1      Col2   Col3
# 0  File1  FirstName  LastName    NaN
# 1  File2         ID      City  State
```