# Converting rows of the same group to one single row with Dask Dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I have a dask dataframe that look like this:

```
group index col1 col2 col3
1     1     5    3    4
1     2     4    3    7
1     3     1    2    9
-----------------------
2     2     4    3    7
2     3     1    2    9
2     4     7    4    3
-----------------------
3     3     1    2    9
3     4     7    4    3
3     5     6    3    2
```

It´s basically a rolling window where each group has its row and x more rows on the dataset. I need to change it to something like this:

```
group col1_1 col2_1 col3_1 col1_2 col2_2 col3_2 col1_3 col2_3 col3_3
1     5      3      4      4      3      7      1      2      9
2     4      3      7      1      2      9      7      4      3
3     1      2      9      7      4      3      6      3      2
```

so for each group I have a row that contains all the values in that group. The number of rows per group is constant but can change, meaning it could be 10, but it would be 10 for the whole dataset. In pandas I found some way to do it using this code that I found in this page: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47849364/pandas-convert-columns-to-new-rows-after-groupby).

```
indexCol = dff.index.name
dff.reset_index(inplace=True)
colNames = dff.columns    
df = pd.pivot_table(dff, index=[indexCol], columns=dff.groupby(indexCol).cumcount().add(1), values=colNames,
                            aggfunc='sum')
df.columns = df.columns.map('{0[0]}{0[1]}'.format)
```

The problem is that dask pivot table does not work like pandas and for what I have read it does not admit multiindex so this code does not work with dask dataframes. I can´t make compute() in the dask dataframe neither because the dataset is too big for my memory so I should keep it in dask.

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

Well, I figured it out at the end so I post it here:

```
def series(x):
    di = {};
    for y in x.columns:
        di.update({y + str(i + 1): t for i, t in enumerate(x[y])})
    return pd.Series(di);
dictMeta = {};
for y in colNames:
    dictMeta.update({y + str(i + 1): df[y].dtype for i in range(0, int(window))})
lista = [(k, dictMeta[k]) for k in dictMeta.keys()]
#We create the 2d dataset for the model
df = dff.groupby(indexCol).apply(lambda x: series(x[colNames]), meta= dictMeta)
```

where colNames are the columns of the original dataset (col1, col2 and col3 in the question) and indexCol is the name of groupby column (group in the question). Basically we create a dictionary for each group and append it to the dataframe as a row. The dictMeta creates the meta since sometimes errors happen without it.